# How to create a mutliple search SQL statement where all the parameters are optional?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I would like to know if there is any smart way of making a SQL statement for a search engine where there are 5 optional parameters. All parameters can be used or only one of them, or a mix of any of them.. This makes up to 3000+ different combinations.

The statement needs to be prepared to avoid SQL injections.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858880/java-jdbc-multi-parameter-search-best-practice) post, but it dosent quite cut.

What I'm looking for is something like,

String sql =SELECT * FROM table WHERE (optional1)=? AND (optional2)=? AND (optional3)=? AND (optional4)=? AND (optional5)=?

prepared.setString(1, optional1)
and so on...

Comment: WAIT! Please tell me how can you make 3000+ different combinations with 5 parameters? To best of my knowledge, total number of combinations = **5C0+5C1+5C2+5C3+5C4+5C5 = 32**

Comment: 5 different parameters that can be combined in any way is 5 to the power of 5, that gives 3125 different combinations. Or am I thinking in the wrong way?

Comment: @keloch - Think of it using binary flags.  If you have none of the 5 parameters, you have combination number 00000, if you have parameters 1,3,5 then you have combination 10101, if you have all 5 parameters then you have combination 11111.  The number of combinations = 2^5 = 32.

Comment: You can see from Dems representation also supports my calculation of **32**, I used mathematical combination (choosing one or more from a group where order does not matter, nCr) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: @SarwarErfan Yea i understand that now, think my brain is working on overtime thus simple things like these become hard :(

Answer (score 3):

Use your java code to add the options to the where clause based on the presence of your arguments (their length or existence, whichever).  That way if the optional parameter is not needed, it won't even be part of your SQL expression.  Simple.

Comment: This is Dynamic SQL, which, while powerful, can occasionally be a pain to deal with; this may be a factor if you're attempting to build the entire query, and so have to keep checking if you've added a `WHERE` clause, or related statements.  The OP seems to be looking for something where the statement is pre-built (completely static), and certain portions are evaluated only if the relvant parameter is provided.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it should work (haven't tested though)

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
field1 = CASE
WHEN ? IS NULL THEN field1
ELSE ? 
END  AND
field2 = CASE
WHEN ? IS NULL THEN field2
ELSE ? 
END  AND .... etc

//java code
if ([optional1 is required]) 
{
  prepared.setString(1, optional1) ;
  prepared.setString(2, optional1) ;
}
else
{
    prepared.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) ;
    prepared.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) ;
}
```

etc.

Comment: problem for me is that option1 isn't always needed, ie. option's 1,2,3,4 not needed in first case, in second case options 2,5 are needed and so on

Comment: @keloch - I think you're missing the point of a1ex07's answer.  In this answer, if you don't have a parameter that you need to filter on, you make that parameter NULL.  a1ex07's CASE statements then check for the NULL and always return TRUE if that particular parameter is NULL.  And by always returning TRUE, it's the same as disabling that condition.  [Note for a1ex97: there is a typo; 2nd case has field1 instead of field2 written in the CASE statement.  Also, the layout is a bit hard to read...]

Comment: @Dems Once again you are correct my friend. Will try this and post back if it worked or not!

Comment: @keloch - Check my answer for a caveat on this approach though ;)

Comment: What if the value to be passed for a parameter is NULL? for example, want to get all the results where field1 is NULL?

Comment: @SarwarErfan - That's a whole new game as `=` won't work for checking for NULLS anyway.  So, yes, you're right, this doesn't allow for your scenario.  It is, however, another justification for building up the WHERE clause dynamically and only including the conditions you need.

Comment: @SarwarErfan That isn't an issue in the DB i have, no NULL values are allowed for the fields that are being searched for. Good call though

Answer (score 3):

@a1ex07 has given the answer for doing this as a single query.  Using NULLs and checking for them in each condition.

```
WHERE
  table.x = CASE WHEN @x IS NULL THEN table.x ELSE @x END
```

or...

```
WHERE
  (@x IS NULL OR table.x = @x)
```

or...

```
WHERE
  table.x = COALESCE(@x, table.x)
```

etc, etc.

There is one warning, however; As convenient as it is to make one query to do all of this, *All* of these answers are sub-optimal.  Often they're horednous.

When you write ONE query, only ONE execution plan is created.  And that ONE execution plan must be suitable for ALL possible combinations of values.  But that fixes which indexes are searched, what order they're searched, etc.  It yields the least worst plan for a one-size-fits-all query.

Instead, you're better adding the conditions as necessary.  You still parameterise them, but you don't include a condition if you know the parameter is NULL.

This is a good link explaining it further, it's for MS SQL Server specifically but it's generally applicatble to any RDBMS that caches the plans after it compiles the SQL.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: Would this work on a sqlite server? That's what I'm using for this application. ps. MS sends chills down my spine :)

Comment: @keloch - I don't know if SQLite caches explain plans at all.  But the approach of building your WHERE clause in Java (and so only supplying the parameters you need) will be effective on all platforms to my knowledge.

Comment: DB2 (for the iSeries, at least) will cache something like the last 150 plans, at least for cursors (... per unique name.  Name your cursors differently, please.  It'll also cache Dynamic SQL, to an extent); some validation is performed when the statement is called, but replans can be rare.  I believe the optimizer will also recognize (and optimize away) the 'boolean flag' variations.